# Jquery .live() нужен аналог. on() не добавляется созданным элементам. А live обещал это делать, как теперь быть?

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

На странице создаются элементы. Я хочу, чтобы на них появлялись обработчики событий автоматически. Читаю про `live()` и понимаю: то что нужно!

Но, оказывается, эту функцию уже удалили. Есть какой-то способ заменить `live?` Потому как в противном случае придется сначала удалить все обработчики событий, а затем установить их снова.

Comment: что ж вы там такое читайте, если в доках в одном и том же предложении указано, что удалено и на что менять? _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers_

Comment: Проблема в том... что on не срабатывает на появившихся элементах. А live обещает это делать. Нужна замена именно в этом. Чтобы не приходилось добавлять обработчики на появившиеся элементы

Comment: дак вы почитайте как `on`  используется вообще

Comment: @E1mir, Спасибо! То что нужно! Действительно тот ответ подходит

Comment: @Igor Пожалуйста, я рад что помог вам найти ответ :)